# CrashPlan requests network connection on startup

Tags: macos, network, security, firewall

Since upgrading to Mavericks, CrashPlan requests incoming network connections each time my MBP is restarted. I always click "Allow" and I've ensured that my firewall settings allow it, but I still get the alert.

I've followed the [instructions](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/CrashPlan_App_3.6.3_Prompts_For_Firewall_Exception) from Code42 support, but the issue persists.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I've read (some time ago) that changes to the requested ports or changes to the program executable itself will generate a new request.

Comment: CrashPlan support told me it's a known issue, but they don't have a fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

My previous response confirmed that the status had not changed since June (4 months ago). I also confirmed that the problem still exists in Yosemite. ie this is still an open issue without a known resolution.

I've looked a bit further into this issue.  The current version of CrashPlan is 3.6.4.

To resolve this issue: 
 - Download the current version
 - Use the 'uninstall' script on the disk image to remove your current installation.
 - Reboot.
 - Install the new version

This also resolves some issues with display and Wireless network detection under Yosemite.

I've not tested to see if just upgrading over the top of the old installation also fixes the issue.